# require() returning different types for same module

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a module A, something like this:

```
module.exports = function() {}
```

which is used by another module B.  if I look at the type returned by `require` it indicates *object*:

```
var a = require('./A');
console.log(typeof a);
```

but if I include it in the test for B, the type returned is *function*:

```
var a = require('../src/A');
console.log(typeof a);
```

how can that be?? the return value should be *function* for both and the only thing that's different in the code is the path to the file... the files are: `src/A.js`, `src/B.js` and `test/B.js`

help?

Comment: I run it like this ->  `node src\B.js` returned `function`, then `node test\B.js` again returned `function`, I'm using v5.5.0, which node version you are using?

Comment: Can not reproduce, for me typeof  `a` is always returned as a function (Node 5.3.0)

Comment: Do you have some kind of circular dependency in your project that would make `require()` return an empty object?

Comment: I'm on 5.0.0 - so I guess I should upgrade.  Bergi, yes... I think that was it.  in the real code I had a circular dependency but in the test code above I didn't.  I'll try to do an upgrade and see if that fixes the issue